# Pass parameters in the new command so that it can be utilized in the whole document

Tags: alignment, renewcommand

I want a define a new command so that once I pass the value as ANNEXURE-I it should be right aligned, bold, underlined, and the font should increase. Moreover, I want the whole document to be justified so that when we continue writing, it will come to the following line automatically. I am attaching the image which I require as the output[image: Desired Output]
I have written few thing in Latex
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

```
% Handling the crossover of intersecting lines
% Author: Steffen Knoll
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% Set page size and margins
% Replace `letterpaper' with `a4paper' for UK/EU standard size
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{flushright}
\textbf{ANNEXURE-I}
\end{flushright}

\begin{center}
 \textbf{To be executed by team}
\\[6.0ex]
\end{center}
I, .................................................................................... (Name of the candidate)\\ No........................................................... S/D/o...................................\\
resident of.......................................................do hereby 

\newpage
\begin{flushright}
\textbf{ANNEXURE-II}
\end{flushright}

\begin{center}
 \textbf{To be executed by team}
\\[6.0ex]
\end{center}
I, .................................................................................... (Name of the candidate)\\ No........................................................... S/D/o...................................\\
resident of.......................................................do hereby 



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
% Handling the crossover of intersecting lines
% Author: Steffen Knoll
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% Set page size and margins
% Replace `letterpaper' with `a4paper' for UK/EU standard size
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\newcommand{\annex}[1]{%
\begin{flushright}
\large\textbf{\underline{#1}}
\end{flushright}%
}
\begin{document}
\annex{ANNEXURE-I}

\begin{center}
\textbf{To be executed by team}
\\[6.0ex]
\end{center}
I, .................................................................................... (Name of the candidate)\\ No........................................................... S/D/o...................................\\
resident of.......................................................do hereby 

\newpage
\annex{ANNEXURE-II}

\begin{center}
\textbf{To be executed by team}
\\[6.0ex]
\end{center}
I, .................................................................................... (Name of the candidate)\\ No........................................................... S/D/o...................................\\
resident of.......................................................do hereby 

\end{document}
```